# Printing only the first level attributes in the hierarchy of a variable in PHP

Tags: php, doctrine

I want to print entities in PHP for debug purposes with `print_r()` or `var_dump()`. The entities are loaded via doctrine/symfony from the database and some of them have a lot of
attributes attached. Example:

```
file
- id
- name
- extension
- fileGroups
- ...
```

fileGroups is a list of objects of another entity:

```
fileGroup
- id
- name
- client
- ...
```

Client is a another entity ... and so forth.

Now when I execute `print_r($file)`, I would like to have only the first list of attributes printed and not the ones below in the hierarchy (because that causes a lazy loading and a memory error in many cases and I'm not interested in that data in the first place).

Is there a possibility to tell PHP to only print certain attribute hierarchies (like only first hierarchy or first and second)?
Or is there a way to tell doctrine to not load attributes (maybe with a parameter), if they are printed via PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($variable, 1);
```

Comment: That works, thanks. But it tells me the method is deprecated and [Symfony var dumper](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html) should be used instead. The Symfony var dumper is what I was looking for. Nice!